# Convertir a Bytes en una columna cuando la esta acompañado el numero de las cadenas GB, MB, KB, B en python 3

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente codigo que en la misma columna tengo valores como 1.7GB, 23M, 33KB, 30B los en los cuales tengo enteros y flotantes, quiero quitar la cadena y convertirlo a bytes esa columna.

```
def conv_bytes(x):
    if 'GiB' in x:
        multiplier=1000000000
    if 'MB' in x:
        multiplier=1000000
    if  'kB'in x:
        multiplier=1000 
    if  'k' in x:
        multiplier=1000
    if  'B' in x:
        multiplier=1
    x = float(x.replace('GiB', '').replace('MB', '').replace('kB', '').replace('k', '').replace('B', ''))*multiplier
    return x

df['Block_Input_CM'] = df['Block_Input'].apply(conv_bytes)

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-07aa015067b2> in <module>
----> 1 df['Block_Input_CM'] = df['Block_Input'].apply(conv_bytes)

c:\users\osval\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4106             else:
   4107                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4108                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4109 
   4110         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-38-5eff734d9cb9> in conv_bytes(x)
      1 def conv_bytes(x):
----> 2     if 'GiB' in x:
      3         multiplier=1000000000
      4     if 'MB' in x:
      5         multiplier=1000000

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable**
```

> Alguna idea para resolver esta punto, Gracias!!!!!!

Comment: El error pareciera indicar que le estarías pasando un `int`  a la función  `conv_bytes()` en vez de un `string`, revisa la columna `df['Block_Input']` ¿es realmente una cadena?

Comment: No creo que se pueda sacar mucho del error con solo mostrar la función, pues ni sabemos cual es la entrada o parámetro, recomiendo que muestres un poco más

Comment: Quedo Arreglado: